# SparkContext Not Being Initialized after sbt run

Tags: scala, sbt

I have my `build.sbt` file below:

```
name := "hello"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val sparkVersion = "1.6.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % sparkVersion
)
```

I also have example.scala in `src/main/scala/example.scala`:

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

object WordCount {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("wordCount").setMaster("local")
      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
      val input =  sc.textFile("food.txt")
      val words = input.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
      val counts = words.map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey{case (x, y) => x + y}
      counts.saveAsTextFile("output.txt")
    }
}
```

For some reason when I do `sbt run` in my root directory (not `src/main/scala`) I get the error:

```
[info] Running WordCount 
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/06/21 22:05:08 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.1
16/06/21 22:05:08 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/06/21 22:05:09 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.net.UnknownHostException: LM-SFA-11002982: LM-SFA-11002982: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1475)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.findLocalInetAddress(Utils.scala:788)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress$lzycompute(Utils.scala:781)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress(Utils.scala:781)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$localHostName$1.apply(Utils.scala:838)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$localHostName$1.apply(Utils.scala:838)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localHostName(Utils.scala:838)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:420)
    at WordCount$.main(exam.scala:8)
    at WordCount.main(exam.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sbt.Run.invokeMain(Run.scala:67)
    at sbt.Run.run0(Run.scala:61)
    at sbt.Run.sbt$Run$$execute$1(Run.scala:51)
    at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Run.scala:55)
    at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Run.scala:55)
    at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Run.scala:55)
    at sbt.Logger$$anon$4.apply(Logger.scala:84)
    at sbt.TrapExit$App.run(TrapExit.scala:248)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: LM-SFA-11002982: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1295)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1471)
    ... 23 more
16/06/21 22:05:09 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
```

Can someone please explain to me the problem stated in this error? Is this because my dependencies were not installed correctly or is it because of another reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the hostname of your system cannot be resolved to an IP address.

As a [ pretty lame ] workaround you can try:

```
echo "127.0.0.1 LM-SFA-11002982" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

Comment: The hostname you statically used can change. This might happen, e.g. when you connect your machine to another network. Depending on your OS there are better ways to setup hostname resolution, e.g. via `hostname` command.

Comment: On the Mac, `sudo hostname LM-SFA-11002982.local` does the job